# Join incomplete string Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, string, serial-port

I'm not sure how to title this, let alone explain it well, but here it goes.

I currently have this method:

```
- (void) receivedData:(NSString *)data {
}
```

It triggers when serial data is read. The serial data is coming in as :`<DMX>255,23,1,4,6</DMX>` problem is, it's not coming in as one unified string. It comes in pieces. Like, `<DM` , `X>255` , `,23,1,4,` , etc. It's random so I can't track it. Sometimes it sends the whole thing, others it sends every couple characters at a time. It is what it is.

How, in my code, can I wait for the whole thing to come in (starting at `<DMX>` and ending at `</DMX>`) and then create an NSString? Maybe as the data comes in, store the pieces, wait for the end `</DMX>`, then combine them together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If You are parsing XML, and have an option of using XML parser - use it (there are builtin XML Parsers in iOS/OSX, as well as numerous other options).
2. If however, you decide to code this instead...

Create `NSMutableString` *ivar* and keep adding (`appendString`) to it as you receive data...
Then keep track of whether you met your start/end tags already...

Something along these lines..

In `MyClass.h`:

```
@interface Myclass : NSObject
{
    NSMutableString *buffer, *tmpBuffer;
    int status; // 0=waiting for <DMX>, 1=recording, 2=done
}
```

In `MyClass.m`:

```
-(id) init {
  if(self = [super init]) {
    buffer = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    tmpBuffer = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    status = 0;
  }
  return self;
}

-(void) receivedData:(NSString *)data {
  if(status == 2) return; // already done

  // status=0 means we are still looking for start tag
  if(status == 0) {
    // add new data to last examined chunk (if any)
    [tmpBuffer appendString:data];

    // try to locate the open tag inside the tmpBuffer
    NSRange range = [tmpBuffer rangeForString:@"<DMX>" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    // if found, store the portion after the start tag into buffer
    if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
      range.length = [tmpBuffer length] - range.location + 5; // 5 is length of start tag...
      [buffer setString:[tmpBuffer substringWithRange:range]];
      status = 1; // set status to 1 so we know recording started
    } else {
      // store last examined chunk
      [tmpBuffer setString:data];
    }
  }
  else {
    [buffer appendString:data];
    NSRange range = [buffer rangeForString:@"</DMX>" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
      range.length = [buffer length] - range.location;
      [buffer deleteCharactersInRange:range];
      status = 2;
    }
  }
}

-(void) dealloc {
  [buffer release];
  [tmpBuffer release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: How can I start when '<DMX>' comes in and end it when '</DMX>' comes in?

Comment: Mm.. this will be harder, but hold on a few minutes ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, Poncha :) I guess to add on top of this, sometimes it won't come in as a full '<DMX>' or '</DMX>'. It might come in as '<D' and 'MX>' or '</', 'DMX', '>'. It's unfortunately random.

Comment: OSX? NSXMLDocument is way easier than this homemade thing :) on ios NSXMLParser. @poncha not that your code is wrong

Comment: I agree, if you have an option of using an XML parser, then this is always a preferred way... I mean, How will you handle an input with `<![CDATA[<DMX>DMX injection ;)</DMX>]]>` ?

Comment: Well, I have code that parses '<DMX>255,255,255,255,255</DMX>'. I just need to get the "parts" together

Comment: added more code to the sample, that tracks start/end tags. but you should still consider using an XML parser instead of doing this. Also note that i don't have xcode here so i cant run the code and validate it ;) so you might get compilation errors if you just copy-paste it ;)

Comment: you can get away with using just one buffer here, too, but i am too lazy to rewrite this once again ;)))

Comment: One more question - how/where do I convert the nsmutablestring to nsstring? I tried doing this : [NSString stringWithString: buffer] right before [buffer deleteCharactersInRange:range]; but the app is crashing.

Comment: You do not need to convert it. NSMutableString is subclass of NSString so it will be accepted by any class/method you pass NSString to